# Better solution for a resizable and dynamic bidimensional array

Tags: c++, c++11

hi I must create a dynamic bidimensional vector.
Being bidimensional I think is better don't use boost.MultiArray for efficiency rasons (overhead for handle vector with greater than 2 dimensions).
My data structure must change row dimension at run-time, rather columns size is fixed i.e. is two.

I thought something like this:

```
vector<vector<unsigned int> > grid;//declaration
vector<unsigned int> row(2);
grid.push_back(row);//copy vector row and insert in grid
```

My questions are:
 is this a good way to accomplish my intent? I think that is inefficient, expensive. What happen when I call push_back?
Or there is a better way that I ignore?
And more, is there a possibility of specify in the declaration that inner vector is of size two?
(compiler is c++11)

Comment: I think it's depend on your input. You can actually treat it like a reguler 2D array. So, grid[0].push_back(1); may work too.

Comment: If the size is fixed, use a `std::array`.

Comment: #AchmadJP but when size overcome capacity what happen? I think something of expensive. Can I avoid or limit it?

Comment: # T.C. namely I should do vector<unsigned int [2] > grid ?

Comment: The capacity is actually quiet BIG, to check it, you can do cout << myvector.max_size(); **NB : to reply a comment, tag the person with @nick** Reading source : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/

Comment: When I say `std::array`, I mean `std::array`. Not a built-in one.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should avoid a vector-of-vectors - that will scatter your data all over memory.  Not only will it occupy more memory than you need, you will also have cache locality trouble when you try to use the data.

All you need is a simple datatype such as `std::array`, `std::pair`, or `std::tuple`.  *e.g.*

```
std::vector< std::array< int, 2 > > grid;
grid.push_back( { 5, 3 } );
```

As for resizing the vector, that is always going to happen.  But the cost is amortized linear time (i.e. it does periodically need to reallocate and copy, but that happens exponentially less frequently as the size increases exponentially).

If you actually *know* how many elements you might need, you can avoid unnecessary resizing up front by using `std::vector::reserve`.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried so that seems simplest:                                         vector<unsigned int [2] > grid ;
unsigned int a[2];
 a[0]=0;
a[1]=1;
 grid.push_back(a);    but don't compile

Comment: I discovered that I cannot store arrays in a vector or any other container. The type of the elements to be stored in a container must be both copy constructible and assignable. Arrays are neither.

Comment: Then your best bet is `std::pair` or define your own struct.